# Name of Homeric (?) figure of speech: semantic transposition

Tags: homer, figurae-sermonis

I'm afraid my question is somewhat vague, and I'll try to improve it as I find the time to research it more.

I've been having a nagging memory of my Ancient Greek and Latin classes (and in that memory this was related to Homer), where we analysed a poetic practice consisting of applying, say, an adjective describing a word X to a nearby word Y, for instance for a poetic effect. This idea seems pretty clear to me, but I am at a loss finding a name for it, and I'm guessing there must be one.

Examples (all fictitious, if I find one in the literature I'll add it, but right now I don't have one at hand):

- "The *bloody* clouds hovered over the *battlefield*" (bloody applied to clouds instead of battlefield)
- "As the Acheans waited, a *grief-stricken* storm was rising to the North" (*grief-stricken* Acheans)
- "And then the *queen* lifted her *amorous* cup and greeted him" (*amorous* queen...)

A friend mentioned chiasmus, which, seems to me, would require the last leg, to get any sort of ABBA cross pattern, even if conceptual, whereas here we only have AB + C becoming B + AC, as it were, applying to objects or atmospheres the internal states of people present, in a gesture of semantic transposition.

Has anyone else heard of this, or am I just hallucinating this memory?

Many thanks in advance,

Best,

Jeremie

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At least one term for this is 'transferred epithet.' It's one species of a more general figure of speech called *hypallage*, an interchange in the relation of words.

It isn't confined to Homer. For example, in Ovid, *Amores* 1.11.3, we find:

> *colligere incertos et in ordine ponere crines
>
> docta neque ancillas inter habenda Nape,
>
> inque **ministeriis furtivae** cognita **noctis**
>
> utilis et dandis ingeniosa notis
>
> saepe venire ad me dubitantem hortata Corinnam,
>
> saepe laboranti fida reperta mihi –
>
> accipe et ad dominam peraratas mane tabellas
>
> perfer et obstantes sedula pelle moras!*
>
> ...known as useful in **services of the secret night**...

Here, *furtivae* grammatically modifies *noctis* but more logically belongs with *ministeriis* ('secret services of the night').

Comment: Grand! Thanks so much, it had been bugging me for so long!